# Can't use aws cloudformation select and findinmap

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Cannot use aws cloudformation Fn::Select and Fn::FindInMap.

Here is the .yaml I wrote:

```
Mappings:
  Parameter:
    AvailabilityZone:
      prod: 'ap-northeast-2a, ap-northeast-2c'
      qa: 'ap-northeast-1a, ap-northeast-1c'

.
.
.
PrivateSubnet:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
  Properties:
    AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, [ !FindInMap [ Parameter, AvailabilityZone, prod ] ] ]
```

output :

```
(ap-northeast-2a, ap-northeast-2c)
```

I tried referring to the following link, but it didn't work.

https://newbedev.com/can-findinmap-return-a-list

output :

```
(ap-northeast-2a)
```

Because the parentheses are also output, AvailabilityZone does not recognize it.

Is there any way to get the correct value through Fn::Select?

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persists?

Comment: @Marcin No... I tried it but it doesn't work I get the following error:
```
Value (ap-northeast-2a) for parameter availabilityZone is invalid. subnets can currently only be created in the following availability zones: ap-northeast-2a, ap-northeast-2c.```

Comment: This is new issue caused by AWS lack of capacity or restricting your account. The original issue that you reported regarding "parentheses are also output" and how to select the AZ seems to be solved, as you get new error, which means that the selection was successful.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. Explicitly declaring ap-northeast-2a works fine.

Comment: So can you provide complete and reproducible example of your code?

Answer (score 2):

You have to `Split` first:

```
    AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !Split [",", !FindInMap [ Parameter, AvailabilityZone, prod ] ] ]
```